# Action Required: Your app is not compliant with Google Play Policies (Data Safety Section)

Tags: android, apk, google-play-console, app-update

The below error is encountered when an app APK update is pushed to google play developer console. The have rejected the app update because of this. The app does not send out any information and is completely offline.

- It uses google location API for getting and storing approximate location (stored only in device and not transmitted anywhere outside)
- It uses a send log functionality for any crashes manually. User is given a choice to send an email and the crash log is attached with the email to developer. This is also not automatic and is controlled by user.

No data is sent from the app to external APIs or systems and the app is completely offline.

Can anyone point me in the right direction on what needs to be done so that the google data safety won't trigger this issue?

[image: google play developer console screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have already submitted Data Safety Form. I suggest to review your Data safety Form & Try updating answers for every cases mentioned in the issue reported by Google Play Policies

If you are passing data to any analytics platform from your app using their APIs.

Select Yes in this section:
[image]

If your app is offline & you are collecting any data from User,
Make sure you tick all the details collected by you in app from the User.

For Example: If you are colecting/sharing Name,Age & Email Address of your User. You need to tick mark all the checkboxes shown under Data Safety Form > Data Types > Personal Details Section

Hope it will help you!

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. I don't do analytics as well. Let me revisit the form and try again.